# Choosing up a Ruby / rails enviroment under windows 8

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, development-environment, environment

I am a junior programmer and beginning web developer seeking to build a reasonable developement enviroment under windows 8. I bought a new computer a few days ago and for a bunch of different reasons i'm stuck in Win8 for a while to come (let's not get into the specifics of that).

From what I have found on the net, developing in the middle of Windows is at best not worth it, so I'm seeking to set some kind of VM running a unix system. I can hanlde the setup itself, but i'm a bit lost at what ind of VM-ware system i should set up.

I want a unix (i'm thinking Fedora) system with packet manager and terminal but also a graphical text editor and the option of storing(using) files on my windows filesystem.

Do anyone have a suggestion about what kind of system i should consider?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Ruby on Windows is ok, but VM is the way to go.

[Here's my write up on how to get VM on Windows](http://serv.github.com/chapter/1-overview/#1_overview)

Go all the way down to the section on Windows.

Once you install Ubuntu VM on Windows, follow the Ubuntu section in getting Ruby.

Comment: +1. I spent a ton of time trying to get Ruby on Rails working "properly" in pure Windows. Never got there. I'd just use VirtualBox and develop on Linux like everybody else!

Comment: Alright. From what i remember of a previous experiment with VB you can't access files from the original filesystem. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: There's probably a way to do it, but I am not aware of it. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

[Vagrant](http://www.vagrantup.com/) is what you want. They changed the logo from an actual vagrant to a synthetic V :-(